# compare strings in two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables with two columns:

**Table1**  `table1`
**Columns** `id, address1`

**Table2** `table2`
**Columns** `id, address2`

I just wont to compare the addresses in the column `address1` with column `address2` to find out duplicate addresses. The `table2.address2` contains some addresses from `table1.address1`

If there is a match then, make an update for example on the `table2` column `match` put `1` else put nothing...

Column `match` is just an example!!!

**here is what i have:**

```
// table 1
$query = "SELECT id, address1 FROM table1";
$sqldata = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQL_BOTH) ) {

    $kr_id = $row['id'];
    $address1 = $row['address1'];   
}


// table 2
$query = "SELECT id, address2 FROM table2";
$sqldata2 = mysql_query($query);        
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sqldata2, MYSQL_BOTH) ) {

    $id = $row2['id'];
    $address2 = $row2['address2'];

  if ($row2[$address2] == $address1) {                               
    // make an SQL - Update
  } 
}
```

thans for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use update with join:

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
 ON(t1.mk_adress = t2.adress)
SET t2.match = 1
```

You may have to adjust the column names a little bit, couldn't figure out which table you want to be updated.

Comment: hi Sagi, for first thank you for your answer. But i need it in php code. because of the log files and some other things.